# directx9, can i use only vertex shader without pixel shader?

Tags: shader, directx-9

i have my game program working with directx9.

For some reaseon, I try to turn off pixel shader, But I want to still use vertex shader. It works on my computer, but i'm not sure about all computers.

Is it possible?

some players have lag on my game, they have graphic card as not good as i recommended one. and i assumed that my shader effects using pixel shader is one reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Direct3D 9 if you have 'no pixel shader set', then you are using the legacy fixed-function pipline (aka the 'texture stage states'). In older shader models with Direct3D 9 you were allowed to mix the legacy pipeline with the programmable pipeline.

> Shader Model 3.0 is more strict. You can't mix the legacy fixed-function pipeline with a [Shader Model 3.0 shader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147365.aspx).

With Direct3D 10 or later, there is no legacy fixed-function pipeline and you must provide at a minimum a VS and PS for rendering.

> Modern GPUs don't have any hardware implementing the legacy fixed-function pipeline. Instead they create vertex & pixel shaders on-the-fly from the state because they are purely programmable hardware.

Comment: Not true, pixel shader can be omitted (for example, for depth-only passes)